What does "lowest EPU" mean when choosing a seat?
I saw on United Airlines: "lowest EPU"

What does "lowest EPU" mean when choosing a seat?
I unsuccessfully searched on Google the following queries:

"Lowest EPU"
"Lowest EPU" flight seat
"Lowest EPU" seating
"Lowest EPU" air travel


EPU means Economy Plus [Upgrade], which ensures you get a seat with extra legroom and a seat in front of the regular Economy sections. Since, you did not show the complete seating plan of the aircraft, it could not be said with 100% certainty. So, the lowest EPU might mean the selected seat has the lowest price for the upgrade from regular E to EP, hence the term "Lowest EPU".

This doesn't make much sense though. If EPU stands for "Economy Plus Upgrade", I don't see how "low EPU" could mean "cheap". Are you sure about this? Do you have a reference?
